# What is the reason my omniauth facebook login is not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth

I created a facebook omniauth login but the authentication does not seem to be working.

First time signing in, the webpage changed to the facebook webpage and it seemed to work but the redirect went back to my web app login page for some reason. When I clicked on the sign-in button again, my web app does not change the web page but stays there.

However, I see that my URL address changes to [http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up#*=*](http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up#_=_)
right after I click on the sign up button so I was wondering what is going on with my app.

`<%= link_to "Facebook sign in", user_facebook_omniauth_authorize_path %>` is my code for sign in.

My user.rb is

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

         def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
    user.email = auth.info.email
    user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    # If you are using confirmable and the provider(s) you use validate emails, 
    # uncomment the line below to skip the confirmation emails.
    # user.skip_confirmation!
  end
end
end
```

routes.rb is

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
  devise_for :admins, path: 'admins'
  root 'home#index'
  get '/' => "courses#index", as: :user_root
    resources :courses, :lessons
end
```

My server log is:

```
Started GET "/users/auth/facebook" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-19 12:23:43 +0900
I, [2017-07-19T12:23:43.560740 #16988]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Request phase initiated.
Started GET "/users/auth/facebook" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-19 12:23:43 +0900
I, [2017-07-19T12:23:43.693460 #16988]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Request phase initiated.
Started GET "/users/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQD_R5wWm1l62YTZ0RwwruKmlCSoSHtUseMhG_aah_xpDLOWuupBN8giG6qVfIhHvfy8g-gfNtT4rAbZ8AfoWqgfNKRhzjihjibgyPayVlpvWPd_OGUY_q52B_K6w5YK-COk5wSHbyeYxc04MzQsXknD7x7oHbHHdF51I9QLkyKY_NwXFYVwadlZKUJgG_4mOm-bw76QDqLVbVDO8M7APKvmk3Aw4fyRj-71R2GsnVYN_jrDr1sz4zf47Ac5CQTa6R5480m59fZtgpups3W1p4cDIsAnZKZiXuOuFZQ_knIDEKrosH4MmSBRqmlKt900nb_VDnVAhY3WFx8lHIgERkSz&state=e45fcf66f73f4c827eae9dfba1130744b91262fd0422486a" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-19 12:23:43 +0900
I, [2017-07-19T12:23:43.848249 #16988]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Callback phase initiated.
Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook as HTML
  Parameters: {"code"=>"AQD_R5wWm1l62YTZ0RwwruKmlCSoSHtUseMhG_aah_xpDLOWuupBN8giG6qVfIhHvfy8g-gfNtT4rAbZ8AfoWqgfNKRhzjihjibgyPayVlpvWPd_OGUY_q52B_K6w5YK-COk5wSHbyeYxc04MzQsXknD7x7oHbHHdF51I9QLkyKY_NwXFYVwadlZKUJgG_4mOm-bw76QDqLVbVDO8M7APKvmk3Aw4fyRj-71R2GsnVYN_jrDr1sz4zf47Ac5CQTa6R5480m59fZtgpups3W1p4cDIsAnZKZiXuOuFZQ_knIDEKrosH4MmSBRqmlKt900nb_VDnVAhY3WFx8lHIgERkSz", "state"=>"e45fcf66f73f4c827eae9dfba1130744b91262fd0422486a"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."provider" = ? AND "users"."uid" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["provider", "facebook"], ["uid", "1332495676858509"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up
Completed 302 Found in 140ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: @Ronert Can you post the server log when you click on log in with facebook ?

Comment: @Vishal Oh sorry, I should have pasted that from the start. Updated post so that my server log is there.

Comment: i think facebook is not getting email id so that it's not saving the user info